# How to see the process stack in the Sysinternals Process Explorer from a .net console app?

Tags: process-explorer, sysinternals, stack

I am trying to get deeper in the understanding how the OS stacks up the chained function calls. So I created a very simple dotnet console app, see the code below, I call the "Call()" method from the Main method. Run the exe and search for the stack in the process explorer.

But I can't make sense of it. I was expecting to see the stack of the function executions. Is there a better way to find this information in the process explorer or another sysinternals tools?

[image]

```
public class StudyingStackExecution_B
    {
        public void Call()
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            MethodA();
        }
        
        private void MethodA()
        {
            var varA_1 = new object();
            var varA_2 = new object();
            var varA_3 = new object();
            Console.WriteLine("A");
            Console.ReadKey();
            MethodB();
        }

        private void MethodB()
        {
            var varB_1 = new object();
            var varB_2 = new object();
            var varB_3 = new object();
            Console.WriteLine("B");
            Console.ReadKey();
            MethodC();
        }

        private void MethodC()
        {
            var varC_1 = new object();
            var varC_2 = new object();
            var varC_3 = new object();
            Console.WriteLine("C");
            Console.ReadKey(); 
            MethodD();;
        }

        private void MethodD()
        {
            var varD_1 = new object();
            var varD_2 = new object();
            var varD_3 = new object();
            Console.WriteLine("D");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you created a .NET app (managed code) and Process Monitor will not show you stacks from managed code (only native, such as C++).

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436707/2879900

You can use the "Call Stack" window in Visual Studio while debugging to show the current call stack:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2022

> in the Debug menu, select Windows > Call Stack.